# uiprogressview not finishing to 100% visually

Tags: ios, objective-c

I do not get what is going on here. I have a progress bar that gets almost complete but does not show it. If I were incrementing by `.10` it would stop at `.9` or so it looked visually and I can figure out how to fix it.

```
    float total = self.forms.count;

   float calc =  (float)self.progView.progress + (1 / total);
    self.progView.progress = calc;
    if (self.progView.progress == 1 )
    {

        sleep(2);
        self.progView.hidden = YES;
                self.progView.progress = 0;
    }
```

I know it goes into the if statement because it will sleep for 2 seconds like this
[image]

**edit:**

hmm I took out the last 2 lines and it does seem to update the last part it must be an issue with a block I have that it is being called from?

Even with this method wrapped in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` I still have the problem.

**sleep is bad on the main thread:**

here is my new working code:

```
if (self.progView.progress == 1 )
    {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(removeProg) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
```

method

```
-(void)removeProg
{
    self.progView.hidden = YES;
    self.progView.progress = 0;
}
```

Comment: Never sleep on the main thread. Ver bad.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and this helped me get a satisfactory conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all has to do with how drawing works in iOS. It doesn't happen when you ask for it. It happens later! The interface is updated only we come to a "redraw moment". This can only happen after all your code has stopped running. All commands to update the interface are meaningless until then. When the "redraw moment" comes, all the accumulated commands to update the interface are executed. If multiple accumulated commands affect the same feature of the interface, only the last one counts.

So let's examine your code:

```
self.progView.progress = calc;
if (self.progView.progress == 1 )
{
   sleep(2);
   self.progView.hidden = YES;
   self.progView.progress = 0;
}
```

Let's say the `progress` was .9. Now you set the `progress` to `calc` and let's say `calc` is 1. But there is no redraw moment yet so the interface does not change. We still see the thermometer at .9. Your code continues to run, and you set the `progress` to 0. Now your code ends. *Now* there is redraw moment. So the thermometer jumps from .9 to 0 without ever being displayed at 1.

A simple parallel experiment is like this:

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
sleep(2);
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

You'll never see the view become green, because when the redraw moment comes, the last command was to make it red, so that's what appears.

Technically, when the runtime sends you an event that starts your code running, a CATransaction is begun. When all your code finishes running and the runtime's original event completes, the CATransaction is "committed" and we go into a bunch of cleanup. This includes doing all accumulated drawing plus launching any requested animations.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: @BluGeni I don't know what it is you want to accomplish! Your question was, you didn't understand why your code caused the behavior it caused. I explained it.

Comment: @matt I just want to be able to show the progress bar getting to 100% then removing it. It doesnt have to sleep I just put the sleep in there to see if it was visually.

Comment: Nevermind I got it! I will update my question to show what I did if it helps anyone, thanks for your answer it was very helpful to finding the answer

Comment: you must use dispatch_async